# Meta tags on taxonomy term pages not showing(using views 3)

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I have installed [Meta tags module](http://drupal.org/project/metatag), configured it, working well, but on taxonomy term pages: *meta description*, and *meta keywords* not showing. I am using Views to override taxonomy term pages. I tried to set some random words for test purproses(not even tokens), but it's still not working. Anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can offer next solutions:

1. Support of taxonomy term pages generated by views is already included in the
   [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) module since 7.x-1.0-beta2.
2. If you are using the [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) module with version lower than 7.x-1.0-beta2 you can use module [Meta tags term view](https://drupal.org/project/metatag_term_view).
3. Try [Meta tags quick](https://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick).